# C++: Return multiple NEW arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I think this is an easy issue, but it's driving me crazy: I want to return multiple arrays from one method, for which the calling method does not know their size in advance. So I have to create those Arrays inside the method (in contrast to just filling them) and I am not able to return them using `return`.

So what I would want is a method signature like this:

```
void giveMeArray(int[] *anArray)
```

Method signature has only one parameter to simplify the examples, please assume I could also have a signature like

```
void giveMeArrays(int[] *anArray, float[] *anotherArray)
```

Inside that method `giveMeArray` I would construct the array with

```
*anArray = new int[5];
```

and I would call that method using

```
int[] result;
giveMeArray(&result);
```

However, all this (starting with the method signature) is at least syntactically wrong. Please excuse that I don't have the compiler errors at hand by now, I'm pretty sure some of you will know what's wrong.

**EDIT** I *know* that std::vector would be the best (meaning cleanest) approach. However, folks, that wasn't the question.

Comment: In this situation using `std::vector` instead of C arrays can really simplify your interface.

Comment: Are you looking to return 1 array with multiple items in it?  Or multiple arrays with multiple items in each?

Comment: The latter. If I just wanted to return one array that could simply be my return type.

Answer (score 5):

Return a single `vector` (this is C++ afterall)

```
void giveMeArray(std::vector<int>& anArray)
{
   anArray = std::vecotr<int>(5);
}
```

Return a vector of vectors:

```
void giveMeArray(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& anArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void giveMeArray(int **anArray);

int *result;
giveMeArray(&result);
```

Comment: Seems like the direction I wanted. But inside that method, `*anArray = new int[5];` does not work, right? (Sorry, no compiler at hand at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> giveMeArray() {
    std::vector<int> ret;
    ret.resize(5);
    return ret;
}
```

Nice resource cleanup, bounds checking in debug modes, etc. Good for all the family.

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping the arrays in a class or struct.

```
struct Arrays {
    int *ints;
    int intCount;
    double *doubles;
    int doubleCount;
};

Arrays giveMeArrays() {
    Arrays arrays;
    arrays.ints = new int[10];
    arrays.intCount = 10;
    arrays.doubles = new double[20];
    arrays.doubleCount = 20;
    return arrays;
}
```

An alternative is to use a `std::pair<>` or a `std::tuple<>`, but in my experience any use of those eventually becomes a named type. The fact that they are all part of the result of your function suggests they may have enough coherence to be an object. Having a user-defined type makes it easier to pass the data around, and so to refactor code. You may even find that `giveMeArrays()` becomes a member function of this object.

Replacing `ints`/`intCount` with `std::vector<int>` would be better, if possible. If not, you may want to give Arrays more responsibility for memory management, disable copying while allowing moving, and so forth.